# Giving a third party credits for contribution in publishing journal paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission, research-assistantship, affiliation

I have done a masters program and three research papers have been composed as the result.

During my research, I was a part of two collaborative parties, my university and a private research center managed by a private company. Both parties need to have credit from publishing these papers.

- How can I give them the credit if I publish my paper in a journal?
- Can this credit be indexed in ranking systems, so they get a real benefit from it?
- How can I consider more priority for one party over the other, according to their contribution on my research?

Comment: What do you mean by credit?...

Comment: Thanks @Matinking for the edit, when a university student or member  publish a paper they can get benefits by increase their rank, also research center can got indexed in international list.

Comment: They will be charged by the credit (as you defined), if you mention your affiliation under the aegis of their title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to give them credit?**

You indicate your affiliation (i. e., the fact that you was a part of a research center / a university and used their resources) while publishing. You may indicate as many affiliations as you wish; I have definitely seen authors with three affiliations.

**Do they get benefit from you indicating them as affiliations?**

In most cases, they do. A university in my country (Russia) will be ranked higher if its students publish more papers. Both universities and research centers need to show that their students publish papers to justify the use of money they receive through grants. For these purposes, indicating affiliation on a journal paper is usually sufficient. You might want to check with your department to find out if your publication (and you crediting your university in your publication) will benefit them.

**How to assign them priority?**

This is not something I have seen in affiliations. However, you might wish to expand the Acknowledgments section in your article. Indicate which kind of support you received from each party. Acknowledgments section is also a place to indicate if your work was supported through any grants.

Comment: Acknowledgement does not provide an official priority, as the OP is seeking.

Comment: @Matinking But in the absence of an alternative, it at least documents such a priority *somewhere*.

Comment: @schester: If you pay close attention to the criteria and applied regulations within the scientific publication, you would notice that there is such functional alternative... Unless you enlighten us with presentation of a case for that "somewhere"!

Comment: @Matinking, I will be very pleased if you provide a better answer of yours.

Comment: @svavil: In my view, the OP's target will not be sufficed, in a considerable manner, to compose a full answer. He has supposedly discerned yours useful because it is marked as the answer... I just pinpointed a hole within your answer. Good luck...